# Equivalent of control-pgDn in Mac

Tags: macos

On Windows, this combination scrolls right down to the bottom of the screen in most apps. Does Mac have any equivalent? I know fn-down exists but it only scrolls one screen at a time. I am looking for something to take me down to the bottom in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command key + up/down arrow should get you to the top or bottom of a page.